# this.setSate not update how to fix this issue

Tags: reactjs

I  have change function but setState not work how to fix this issue 
all value setState blank how to this issue solve

```
 handleAddressSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let isValidForm = false;
this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
  if (!err) {
    isValidForm = true;
  }
});
if (!isValidForm) {
  return false;
}

if (this.state.flatno) {
  this.setState({
    full_address:
      this.state.flatno +
      "," +
      this.state.address1 +
      "," +
      this.state.suburb +
      "," +
      this.state.state +
      "," +
      this.state.post_code +
      "," +
      this.state.country,
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    full_address:
      this.state.address1 +
      "," +
      this.state.suburb +
      "," +
      this.state.state +
      "," +
      this.state.post_code +
      "," +
      this.state.country,
  });
}

console.log(this.state.is_default);
this.props.addAddressAction({
  flat_no: this.state.flatno,
  address1: this.state.address1,
  address2: this.state.address2,
  suburb: this.state.suburb,
  state: this.state.state,
  postal_code: this.state.post_code,
  country: this.state.country,
  full_address: this.state.full_address,
  lat: this.state.lataddress,
  lang: this.state.lngaddress,
  is_default: this.state.is_default,
});
```

this.setState({
      flat_no: "",
      address1: "",
      address2: "",
      suburb: "",
      state: "",
      postal_code: "",
      country: "",
      full_address: "",
      lat: "",
      lang: "",
      is_default: "",
    });

};

Comment: setState is async, you must put console log as the callback ```this.setState({...}, () => console.log(this.state.init_values)```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read the state value right after calling a state setter (`this.setState` or `setState` from `useState`). You will always have the old values.

You should read it in the next render.

The state setter just tells react to enqueue an update for a component. It doesn't mutate the state right away.

For a complete understanding of what setState does, I recommend [this blog post from Dan](https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do/)

Comment: They could also use the optional callback function as the second parameter, which is guaranteed to execute after the state has been updated.

Comment: yeah I know, but the better way is to treat it like a sideEffect which is the case. I believe the true use case isn't console.log

Comment: after submit form  input not empty how to  after blank form please help me

Comment: In the submit function, you should set state to its initial values, and that all:
`this.setState({ flat_no: "", address1: "", address2: "", suburb: "", state: "", postal_code: "", country: "", full_address: "", lat: "", lang: "", is_default: "", });`

Comment: I have pass empty value but its not work